# About associated Legendre equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there someone that maybe can explain where come from the substitution $y(z) = (1-z^2)^{m/2}\cdot u(z)$ in the associated legendre equation? It come from series power? I can't manage the complete solution of this equation. Actually i need only to understand why we use this substitution.  Sorry my rusty english.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you would like to know, but I will try to
give you some explanantions regarding the relation between Legendre equation and associated Legendre equation.

As you know, Legendre differential equation is,

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(1-x^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-2x\frac{dy}{dx}+n(n+1)y=0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

If you differentiate the above equation once, you obtain,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(1-x^2)\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}-4x\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+[n(n+1)-2]\frac{dy}{dx}=0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Differentiating twice, you obtain,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(1-x^2)\frac{d^4y}{dx^4}-6x\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}+[n(n+1)-6]\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
and so on.

Differentiating $m$ times $(n>m)$, you will find that the general equation can be obtained as,

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(1-x^2)\frac{d^{m+2}y}{dx^{m+2}}-2 (m+1)x\frac{d^{m+1}y}{dx^{m+1}}+[n(n+1)-m(m+1)]\frac{d^my}{dx^m}=0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

You can prove the above relation by the induction method.

Now, if you transform, $y=(1-x^{2})^{m/2}z$ and put it into the differential equation, known as the associated Legendre differential equation below,

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(1-x^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-2x\frac{dy}{dx}+\left[n(n+1)-\frac{m^2}{1-x^2}\right]y=0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

you will see that the equation becomes,

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(1-x^2)^{m/2}
\left
[(1-x^2)\frac{d^{2}z}{dx^{2}}-2 (m+1)x\frac{dz}{dx}+[n(n+1)-m(m+1)]z\right]=0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

So this leads us to the relation,

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
z=\frac{d^my}{dx^m}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

which indicates that, if y is the solution of Legendre differential equation $P_n(x)$,

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
P_n^m(x)=(1-x^{2})^{m/2}\frac{d^my}{dx^m}=(1-x^{2})^{m/2}\frac{d^mP_n(x)}{dx^m}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

will be that of the associated Legendre differential equation.

In this note, please be reminded that I have omitted the discussion of the function of second kind, $Q_n(x)$ and $Q_n^m(x)$, for simplicity. But the story I believe is basically the same.

Hopefully, my explanation serves your question.

*P.S. I have added some replies in response to your comment.

I don't inderstand what is meant by "artificial". The function that satisfies the differential equation written above, *i.e.,*
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(1-x^2)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-2x\frac{dy}{dx}+\left[n(n+1)-\frac{m^2}{1-x^2}\right]y=0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

which is a more general form of Legendre equation, is the associated Legendre function, $P_n^m(x)$ expressed here in the note.

Of course, since the Legendre function is polynomial and can be expressed as, for example,

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
P_n(x)=\sum^{[n/2]}_r(-1)^r\frac{(2n-2r)!}{2^n r!(n-r)!(n-2r)!}x^{n-2r}
=\frac{1}{2^n n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

(ther are several other ways to express the summation form) you can easily see that the associated Legendre function expressed as $(1-x^2)^{m/2}P_n(x)$ is also a polynomial function. For more detail about the form of the polynomial, see for example, "*Handbook of Mathematical Functions*", by M. Abramowitz and I. A. Stegun. If you prefer to use the polynomial form, you can do that, but it's just doing the same thing as I have explained.

In the equation,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(1-x^2)\frac{d^{m+2}y}{dx^{m+2}}-2 (m+1)x\frac{d^{m+1}y}{dx^{m+1}}+[n(n+1)-m(m+1)]\frac{d^my}{dx^m}=0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d^{m+2}y}{dx^{m+2}}=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(\frac{d^{m}y}{dx^{m}}\right)
=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}z
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d^{m+1}y}{dx^{m+1}}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{d^{m}y}{dx^{m}}\right)
=\frac{d}{dx}z
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
and so on, which thereby indicates that the function $(1-x^2)^{m/2}z$ satisfies the associated Legendre differential equation and as a whole the above equation becomes,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(1-x^2)^{m/2}
\left
[(1-x^2)\frac{d^{2}z}{dx^{2}}-2 (m+1)x\frac{dz}{dx}+[n(n+1)-m(m+1)]z\right]=0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

as I have explained in the note.

Comment: Why did you write z=d(^m)y/dx(^m)?

Comment: By the way, i think your explanation very artificial. There must be a more natural one, perhaps  using power series.

Comment: See the replies I have uploaded in addition to my note.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if I shall provide some references, rather to answer the question directly. It will provide you more information about this context.

$1.~~$ "Special Functions for Scientists and Engineers" by W. Bell

(Chapter $~3~$, article $~3.8~$, Page No. $~62~$)

$2.~~$ "Special Functions & Their Applications" by N. N. Lebedev & Richard A. Silverman

(Chapter $~7~$, article $~7.12~$, Page No. $~192~$)

Good Luck.